# Can Pc users without the mechromancer dlc play with a user that has it?

Tags: borderlands-2

I play Borderlands 2 co-op with friends. I was just wondering if I should buy the Mechromancer's pack or not because I don't know if my I can play with people that don't have the DLC due to compatibility issues.

Would I be able to play with them or not?

Note: this is on pc. I already know this is possible on xbox 360.

Comment: Generally, the answer shouldn't be different, regardless of console.  If it turns out this is specific to PC, though, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: I'd imagine you can.  I played with someone that owns the Kreig DLC which I haven't bought yet. (PC, Steam)

Comment: Of course you can. You download all dlc with the updates that Steam/XBOX/whatever throws out. If you don't update, you can't launch the game in case of Steam (dunno about consoles). You have the data of the model and textures, just not the license file to actually use the character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the Mechromancer pack behaves in the same way as the Krieg pack (which is a pretty safe assumption, considering they're both character DLC for the same game...) then **yes**, you can play with someone who has a character you do not.

This happened to me, which is how I'm sure of it - a day after Krieg came out (which I didn't buy) someone using Krieg joined my game and started wantonly setting himself on fire.

Comment: I bought the mechromancer pack, and a friend of mine bought the krieg pack... but neither of us has the other pack and yet we play together. So i'm pretty sure that you don't need the pack to play together with someone that has the pack.

Comment: My regular co-op partner is a mechromancer and I have no DLC, so (at least on PC) it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about other platforms, but at least on Xbox 360 there is a [compatibility pack](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Compatibility-Pack/ca0f1921-1933-49e3-b105-1262dbf98439?cid=SLink) to download. This allows you to play with other players that do not have the same DLC installed.

So as long as you both have downloaded that, you should be fine.

Comment: The PC version automatically downloads the "DLC" needed to play with Mechro players. The PS3 probably either has an update or DLC for the same

Answer (score 1):

On the PC version there's no DLC pack to download, the game will simply patch itself from Steam and you'll be able to play with others just fine.

On consoles there's a compatibility pack due to how updates are released on the consoles (large updates are a no-no on Xbox, fine on steam) but PC users don't have to worry about that. If your game is up to date, you can play with Mechro players on Steam with or without buying the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Source: I didn't have Mechro pack and my friend did, we played together fine. Also on PC.